# Rails & Amazon S3 - how it works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I would like to ask you for a simple beginner's question - I have my app in Rails and it's on Heroku. For storing images use the app S3 by Amazon.
For uploading images I use the Paperclip plugin.

And what I don't understand - I deploy my app from localhost to Heroku. It seems on Heroku my app works fine, I upload the image, this image is stored to S3 and in my app is fine displayed.

But now if I will upload an image on my localhost version - so the image will be uploaded to S3 bucket or will be stored on my hard drive?

Are these two sides separated or if I once set up into my model the S3 support, so that will be mean all images will uploaded to S3 (from heroku and from localhost)?

Comment: The second one: they be in S3 whether the app is run locally or in heroku.

Answer (score 0):

@phs is correct.  The images will be stored on S3 regardless of where you run the app.  This can cause you some grief if your :id is embedded in the image location (which it probably is) and your dev database has different ID's than your production/heroku database.